# Modify Class Object Argument Based On When Calling A Method

Tags: python, object, methods

This is a heavily simplified version of what I am working on, I just don't want to put 5,000 lines in here. So I know this works and all, but I want to be able to have the method"eat" be able to be applied non-specifically to any object that this class parents (such as "John Smith", and adding lets say "Mike Doe".) I would like it to automatically select the person who undergoes ".eat()" to eat food rather than making the method specifically state: `johnSmith.hunger = False`. What I am doing is creating methods of actions people can use within the game that affect other objects (class children and variables), but I don't want to set a method for each action for each character unit. That would be insane. Given below is my set of code.

```
class human():

    def __init__(self, name, hunger):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = hunger

    def eat(self):
        johnSmith.hunger = False
        print("Human Ate Food")

johnSmith = human("John Smith", True)

print("Human Is Hungry:", johnSmith.hunger)
johnSmith.eat()
print("Human Is Hungry:", johnSmith.hunger)
```

If I am unclear (which I know I am Not doing a great job explaining), feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `self`:

```
def eat(self):
    self.hunger = False
    print("%s Ate Food" % self.name)
```